# ClassNotFoundException: org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport

Tags: java, infinispan

this issue drives me crazy 
recently i configured hibernate to work with `infinispan 8.1` 
and just worked fine in debug mode with `eclipse` 
the problem when tried to deploy my application war on `apache tomcat6`

i get this exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: Unable to start region factory
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.start(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:415)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.<init>(CacheImpl.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: Unable to instantiate class org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport
    at org.infinispan.commons.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:103)
    at org.infinispan.commons.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:258)
    at org.infinispan.configuration.global.TransportConfigurationBuilder.defaultTransport(TransportConfigurationBuilder.java:207)
    at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.Parser72.parseJGroups(Parser72.java:405)
    at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.Parser72.readElement(Parser72.java:93)
    at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parseElement(ParserRegistry.java:151)
    at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parse(ParserRegistry.java:131)
    at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parse(ParserRegistry.java:118)
    at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parse(ParserRegistry.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.parseWithOverridenClassLoader(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:518)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.access$000(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory$1.doWork(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory$1.doWork(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.workWithClassLoader(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.createCacheManager(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:469)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.start(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:380)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.infinispan.commons.util.Util.loadClassStrict(Util.java:158)
    at org.infinispan.commons.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:101)
    ... 106 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception clearly shows that jar is not present on class path. For web project see if that jar is present inside lib folder of your war.

Comment: thanks Dash the problem is that this class already exist in its Owen jar in the lib folder the problem only appear when trying to deploy it on tomcat6